# Biblioteca para validações de dados em português brasileiro para Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Sempre que preciso utilizar validações de `cpf` ou `telefone` em Laravel, preciso utilizar o método `Validator::extend` para poder adicionar essas validações.

```
Validator::extend('cpf_real', function($attr, $value)
{

    $c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);

    if (strlen($c) != 11 || preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{11}$/", $c)) {

        return false;
    }

    for ($s = 10, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);

    if ($c[9] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {

        return false;
    }

    for ($s = 11, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);

    if ($c[10] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {

        return false;
    }

    return true;

});
```

Reparei que isso tem se tornado um processo repetitivo e queria remover isso da minha rotina de programação. Toda vez que preciso dessa validação em algum sistema feito em Laravel, sempre preciso usar o CTRL+V nesse código.

Creio que a solução para tal coisa é se houvesse alguma biblioteca para Laravel, com algumas validações para dados Brasileiros prontos (com as mensagens de erro também prontas).

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca para Laravel 4 e Laravel 5, que faça isso?

Preciso que seja para os dois frameworks, pois trabalho exatamente com os dois, pois tenho vários sistemas na empresa onde trabalho. Seria uma "mão na roda" se alguém me ajudasse.

Comment: Ja ouvi falar do PHPlegends. Você conhece? rs , https://github.com/phplegends, Ps: verifica os desenvolvedores fódas dessa biblioteca

Comment: @João é, mas todo o projeto que eu tivesse que iniciar, teria que criar um novo ServiceProvider. E isso é porque você está falando de Laravel 5. Porque também trabalho com o 4 (como já disse na pergunta)

Comment: Já tentou usar esse cara: https://github.com/KennedyTedesco/Validation ?

Comment: Me parece bem mais completo

Comment: Opções são sempre venvidas @gmsantos. Não conhecia, vou dar uma olhadinha

Comment: @gmsantos vi aqui, é realmente bem completa. Vale a pena dar uma olhadinha. Também, né, só podia ser da Respect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim. Tem [Essa](https://github.com/phplegends/laravel-pt-br-validator) que você pode utilizar.

Para instalar via composer no Laravel 4

```
{
    "phplegends/pt-br-validator" : "1.*"
}
```

já no laravel 5

```
{
    "phplegends/pt-br-validator" : "2.*"
}
```

No `app.php` você precisa adicionar o Service Provider da biblioteca.

Laravel 5:

```
PHPLegends\PtBrValidator\ValidatorProvider::class
```

Laravel 4:

```
 'PHPLegends\PtBrValidator\ValidatorProvider'
```

Exemplo do github:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['telefone' => '(77)9999-3333'],
    ['telefone' => 'required|telefone_com_ddd']
);

dd($validator->fails());


Validator::make($valor, $regras, ['celular_com_ddd' => 'O campo :attribute não é um celular'])
```